# Insert a json into mysql with Golang

Tags: mysql, json, go

I want to insert a json object to mysql. The relative code is

```
array := []string{"BT", "TL", "CN"}
s, err := json.Marshal(array)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
_, err := db.Exec("update setting set multilingual = json_set(multilingual, '$.supported', ?) where id = ?", s, 10)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Expected result in the column multilingual is:

```
{"supported": ["BT","TL","CN"]}
```

But I got:

```
{"supported": "[\"BT\",\"TL\",\"CN\"]"}
```

The go library to connect mysql is sqlx.

How can I fix this please.

Comment: Have you tried `CAST(? AS JSON)`?

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you for your advice. I just tried it, but json seems not a valid datatype in the cast function(｡ ́︿ ̀｡).

Comment: Works for me just fine, see [link](https://imgur.com/3l1sds7). And the mysql version that I'm running is `8.0.28`. And if I remove the `CAST` I get the same result as you, see [link](https://imgur.com/oNH9aOO).

Comment: @mkopriva Oh! Thank you! I just typed the wrong word! This gives me exactly what I want! Thank you very much!!! \^O^/